Shopify app　What is the minimum description required to place a draft order on the app?
It seems that it is dangerous to use access tokens on the front end.
In the back end, the app automatically generates access tokens.
I have prepared a template app, but where do I set it?
I tried it as shown below. I also set the scope. I also set the app. I wrote the access token in env.
Frontend
       const response = await fetch('/admin/api/2023-10/draft_orders.json', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'shpat_',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(orderData),

Change the endpoint to:
Frontend
        const response = await fetch('/create-draft-order', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(orderData),
                });

Backend
app/routes/create-draft-order.tsx
  const response = await axios.post('https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/draft_orders.json', orderData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process.env.SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        },
    });

I thought this would handle the endpoints, am I forgetting something?

Can you check in the console if your .env variable SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN is getting consoles correctly? Also, share the exact error you're getting to assess the precise problem you're facing.

Hi thanks you.
I changed the env to client ID and client secret. I'm currently setting the app proxy in the app settings. Subpath prefix, subpath. The proxy URL uses the app URL.
Apparently, in order to run the API on the store, it is necessary to set an endpoint, and to do that, I found out that I needed to set up a proxy in the app settings.
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/build/online-store/display-dynamic-data
